# Forming with absolute value - am I allowed to form it like that?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

So far I didn't face much with absolute value in maths that's why I'm not sure at all if I'm allowed to do the following.

Let's say we have $x,y, \tilde{x},\tilde{y} \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \left\{0\right\}$

$$\frac{\left |\frac{\tilde{x}}{\tilde{y}}-\frac{x}{y}\right |}{\left | \frac{x}{y} \right |}$$

And now I want form it to: $$\frac{\left | \frac{\tilde{x}}{\tilde{y}} \right |}{\left| \frac{x}{y} \right|}-\frac{\left|\frac{x}{y}\right|}{\left|\frac{x}{y}\right|} = \left|\frac{\tilde{x}y}{\tilde{y}x}\right|-1$$

---

Is it correct like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

your first step is wrong because, for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$
$$
|a-b|=\left|(|a|-|b|) \right|
$$

the second step is correct because

$$
\left| \frac{a}{b} \right|=\frac{|a|}{|b|}
$$

---

$$\frac{\left |\frac{\tilde{x}}{\tilde{y}}-\frac{x}{y}\right |}{\left | \frac{x}{y} \right |}=
\left|\frac{\left |\frac{\tilde{x}}{\tilde{y}}\right|-\left |\frac{x}{y}\right |}{\left | \frac{x}{y} \right |}  \right|=
\left|\frac{\left |\frac{\tilde{x}}{\tilde{y}}\right|}{\left | \frac{x}{y} \right |}-1  \right|=\left| \left|\frac{\tilde{x}y}{\tilde{y}x} \right|-1\right|$$

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I got it but then I think there is nothing I can form to make it look more nice / smaller?

Comment: I added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are effectively asking whether
$$\frac{|a-b|}{|b|}=\frac{|a|}{|b|}-\frac{|b|}{|b|}$$
or equivalently, whether
$$\left|\frac ab-1\right|=\left|\frac ab\right|-1.$$
The answer is no; the right hand side may be negative.